# Error 81 when launching web app on Gear S2 device

Tags: certificate, provisioning, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-sdk

I am using Tizen SDK (2.4.0_Rev5) to launch the demo app HelloTizen (wearable-2.3) on my Gear S2 but it fails, with the following error:

```
Unknown Error [81]
 Unknown Error [81]
```

When I try to install it with `sdb install HelloTizen.wgt` I get the following output:

```
pushed                 HelloTizen.wgt   100%         36KB           0KB/s
1 file(s) pushed. 0 file(s) skipped.
/home/user/tizen/HelloTizen/HelloTizen.wgt   114KB/s (37179 bytes in 0.318s)
path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/HelloTizen.wgt
__return_cb req_id[138540002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RFZKe67scd] key[start] val[install]
__return_cb req_id[138540002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RFZKe67scd] key[install_percent] val[3]
__return_cb req_id[138540002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RFZKe67scd] key[install_percent] val[22]
__return_cb req_id[138540002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RFZKe67scd] key[install_percent] val[25]
__return_cb req_id[138540002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RFZKe67scd] key[install_percent] val[33]
__return_cb req_id[138540002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RFZKe67scd] key[error] val[81] error message: Non trusted certificate is used. Register valid certificate
__return_cb req_id[138540002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RFZKe67scd] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : Unknown Error [81] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [1385]ms
```

There is the output from `sdb dlog`:

```
W/WRT_INSTALLER(20115): task_certify.cpp: StartStep(619) > --------- <TaskCertify> : START ----------
E/WMS     (  490): wms_event_handler.c: _wms_event_handler_cb_log_package(4560) > package [_________] callback : [INSTALL, PROCESSING]
E/WMS     (  490): wms_event_handler.c: _wms_event_handler_cb_log_package(4560) > package [_________] callback : [INSTALL, PROCESSING]
E/WMS     (  490): wms_event_handler.c: _wms_event_handler_cb_log_package(4560) > package [_________] callback : [INSTALL, PROCESSING]
E/WMS     (  490): wms_event_handler.c: _wms_event_handler_cb_log_package(4560) > package [_________] callback : [INSTALL, PROCESSING]
W/CERT_SVC(20115): OCSPCertMgrUtil.cpp: getCertFromStore(97) > Error during certificate search
W/CERT_SVC(20115): WrtSignatureValidator.cpp: check(365) > signature1.xml has got unrecognized Root CA certificate. Signature will be disregarded.
W/WRT_INSTALLER(20115): task_certify.cpp: throwCertificateInvalidException(373) > Certificate is Invalid [-34]
E/WRT_INSTALLER(20115): task_certify.cpp: stepSignature(350) > Error occured in signature validator: 81
E/APP2EXT (20115): job_widget_install.cpp: SendFinishedFailure(370) > Error number: 81
E/APP2EXT (20115): job_widget_install.cpp: SendFinishedFailure(371) > Message: Non trusted certificate is used. Register valid certificate
W/WRT_INSTALLER(20115): pkgmgr_signal.cpp: sendSignal(275) > Success to send pkgmgr signal: error - 81:Non trusted certificate is used. Register valid certificate
W/WRT_INSTALLER(20115): pkgmgr_signal.cpp: sendSignal(275) > Success to send pkgmgr signal: end - fail
E/WRT_INSTALLER(20115): wrt-installer.cpp: staticWrtStatusCallback(1102) > Step failed
```

So, it seems to be a certificate related error. I did generate my certificate in `Security Profiles` with one generate author certificate and the automatic certificate for distributor. I also used `Register Certificate` but I do not know if it worked because when I clicked on OK, nothing happened.

The other thing I did was to enable `Permit to install applications` for my device. But, as for the certificate registration, I do not know if it worked because nothing happened. I checked in `/home/developer` and there is no `device-profile.xml` file.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my distributor certificate but I used the default one found in `/tizen/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-signer.p12` and for the CA path `/tizen/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-ca.cer`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you fix it in the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run app in Emulator, then IDE generated certificate will work. But you are running app in Gear S2 which has user binary, that's why you need to get author certificate from samsung. Below link will show you the way of installing extension sdk for certificate for both emulator and device.

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/issuing-tizen-certificate-certificate-extension-ver-1.2

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got the difference between the two certificate methods. When I did try to create a new, I got an error about the browser that cannot be initialized.  As I thought it was possible to use the same certificates, I gave up with that and just used the default ones. I will try to solve my browser problem now. When it will be done, and everything will be working I will accept your answer.