# In Tizen Studio Unexpected error `Installing the package...` Web application (for watch)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am very new to Tizen development. I was trying to run a web application (default BasicUI) in tizen watch gear s3. But getting the following error:

Installing the package... > Fail
Unexpected error occurred at the below step.
 `Installing the package...`
Please try again later.
[image]

Though I when I tried the native app default template and it was okay. I am getting this problem only for web application.

Here I have also given the screenshot from the console.

[image]

I am using version 3 and my operation system is windwos 10. Tried both certificate Tizen and samsung.

Comment: Check your Gear S3 time and Windows time .....if not, make them same

Comment: It happens to me very often. I usually reset Gear S3 and set it up again.

Answer (score 4):

If you run app in Emulator, then IDE generated certificate will work. But you are running app in real Gear which has user binary, that's why you need to get **author certificate** from Samsung. 
Follow [this](https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/1_tizen_studio_windows.pdf) document.

Also make sure that your development machine and Gear **time is synchronized**.

Also these threads may help you.

- [Error 81 when launching web app on Gear S2 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222812/error-81-when-launching-web-app-on-gear-s2-device)
- [Deploying Tizen app to Gear S2: Non trusted certificate is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790473/deploying-tizen-app-to-gear-s2-non-trusted-certificate-is-used)
- [How to install app on Gear S2 via Tizen Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742515/how-to-install-app-on-gear-s2-via-tizen-studio)

Comment: I checked the certificate, it is done accordingly. Also, I tried it in emulator too. There I get this error notification: extra package installation is failed.  cert must be installed MANUALLY!

Comment: Please add screen shots

Comment: Here is the screenshot of what I am getting.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6r4TOn584vSc29GZUNNTnpIOTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I will suggest you to delete all the file in /tizen-studio-data/keystore except author folder. Also delete files of author folder....then create certificate again

Answer (score 1):

Just because your Gear S3 is on Tizen version 2.3.2 ?

Look at : Gear info -> About device -> Tizen version

But I don't understand why the **native** wearable app 3.0 works in my Gear S3 (2.3.2).